# How to unencrypt my data on a Lenovo Tab M8 FHD TB-8705F device

Tags: encryption, lenovo

I'm trying to unencrypt my data on my device.

My device is rooted with Magisk Manager.

This is what I have already tried.

1. Uticked the box Preserve forced encryption in Magisk Manager.
2. Patched the boot image in Magisk Manager.
3. Flashed this patched boot image to my device.
4. Formatted userdata thru ADB.

But after this my userdata is stilled encrypted.

Thank You,
Sruly

Comment: you need to patch ***/vendor/etc/fstab.mt6762*** see this [example](https://github.com/TeamWin/android_device_xiaomi_cereus/blob/android-9.0/recovery/root/etc/recovery.fstab) for userdata partition flag ***encryptable=*** and *'fastboot format:ext4 userdata'*

Comment: Looking at that example I'm not sure what the `encryptable=` should be. There are 2 places in that example that have such a statement.

Comment: /dev/block/platform/bootdevice/by-name/userdata

Comment: @alecxs I have now another device that I'm trying to unencrypt. Even after changing the fstab.mt**** file it goes back to its original form after reboot. I tried to pull the vendor image and changed the file then re-flashed the image. It still goes back to its original state.

Comment: A/B device? Forward Error Correction?

Comment: I'm not familiar with these terms I looked at the link you provided. How can I find out if one of these reasons is my problem? If it is waht can I do about it? Thanks

Comment: i don't know, it's heavily device- and rom- dependent. Open new question with good device description and as much details as possible regarding your problem

Comment: check the universal dm-verity disabler xda thread page 90 there is some info about that